# "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" - React

Tags: reactjs

I have only one button in the form, so the problem is not connected with "if there is more than one button, these types should be button (`type="button"`)".

But I cannot submit the form, instead I get this error on console:
"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Here is the Form code:

```
return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Button className={`text-nowrap m-auto mt-4 ${mutation.isLoading ? 'btn-loading' : 'btn-cancel btn-inverse'}`} type="submit" disabled={mutation.isLoading}>
              {mutation.isLoading ? <Spinner variant="secondary" animation="border" size="sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" /> : "Cancel"}
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of passing `type = "submit"`  pass `htmlType="submit"` to the Button element.
define form variable like this :

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```

and you have to define a function where you want trigger when you click submit

```
function handleSubmit(variables){
   //your code goes here
}
```

and finally your return element should be like this :

```
<Form form={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Button className={`text-nowrap m-auto mt-4 ${mutation.isLoading ? 'btn-loading' : 'btn-cancel btn-inverse'}`} type="submit" disabled={mutation.isLoading}>
              {mutation.isLoading ? <Spinner variant="secondary" animation="border" size="sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" /> : "Cancel"}
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
```

Comment: i can help more if you write handleSubmit function code too . i dont understand what is the onSubmit variable you passing to this function

Comment: It's not even triggered by `htmlType="submit"`. There are no errors in the console and no action like submitting the form. And here is the handleSubmit: `const { handleSubmit, setError, formState: { errors } } = useForm()`. And here is the onSubmit: `const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
    setFormError(null)
    mutation.mutate(formData)
  }`. Also I converted it to arrow func as you mention, but still not working. Rendered result shown as `<button type="button" htmltype="submit" ... >`

Comment: i just dont understand your code so i will change my answer hope it will help you

Comment: Ok here is the full code, I edited based on your feedback but now submit function wasn't triggered at all, this means no error on the console but no submit action as well:
https://i.ibb.co/cg0RCsq/image.png

Comment: Ok now I edited the code again based on your new solution and I started to get the console error again, which is "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Comment: can i see your new code

Comment: Here is the updated code: https://i.ibb.co/yN62Tdj/image.png

Comment: delete first line and add this const [form] = Form.useForm(); and delete onSubmit function and add this function handleSubmit(variables){
   setFormError(false)
   mutation.mutate(variable)
}

Comment: handleSubmit isn't a custom function I wrote, it's a built-in function of react-hook-form. I cannot delete the first row since the project uses these to handle forms. Thank you for trying to help but I think I need something else